# How do you write an array formula based on multiple criteria in MS Excel?

Tags: excel

So I have two columns in MS Excel, Let's call them A and B, and I'm trying to create an array formula that let's me create a list from B, based on a specific paired item on the same row in column A. I know how to write a formula to return a list of unique values from one column, but is there a way to create a unique list from one column based on values from another?

Thanks in advance. I've been using this site for years but never had a question that wasn't answered previously. You've all helped me out so much in the past.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.(Hopefully this makes sense)

[This isn't an exact copy of what I want but it's an approximation. I'm trying to fill out the colors of the corresponding car types without any duplicates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1QEy.png)

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] the post to include a mockup of the data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of getting the unique items in column **B** for column **A** having the value "mike" using Excel 365.  Pick a cell and enter:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B12,A1:A12="mike"))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think my job has a version of excel that has the FILTER function as it's a 365 one from what I've read.